# Convert Hour Minute Second Milisecond to total second.milisecond in latest pandas version

Tags: python, pandas, csv, time

I have csv file with format HH:MM:SS.Milisecond

```
06:37:46.200
06:37:46.600
06:37:47.300
```

I want convert that to

```
23866.200
23866.600
23867.300
```

How to do that in Pandas latest version (1.4)?

I've tried some answers from this forum, but they don't work on csv and latest version of Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
           time
0  06:37:46.200
1  06:37:46.600
2  06:37:47.300
```

You can use [`pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.total_seconds()
```

output:

```
0    23866.2
1    23866.6
2    23867.3
Name: time, dtype: float64
```